# Dynamics CRM Online - Can't open subreport with conditional expression

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, dynamics-crm

I created a report using Visual Studio.
I have a table with one column that contains total won opportunity per account. If an account has total won opportunity more than zero, I want to link the text to a sub report (account detail report). But if it is zero, then I don't want to link it anywhere. So I create an action for '**Go To Report**', and put expression in '**Specify a report**' like this :

```
=IIF(Count(Fields!opportunity_name.Value) > 0, "AccountDetailReport", Nothing)
```

It works well in Preview section, if I clicked on total won opportunity with value more than 0, it will directed to the subreport. But when I uploaded the report to Dynamics CRM online, and tried to click on total won opportunity, it throws an error says : "*Details are not available because subreport is missing*".

I guess it because the conditional expression when I specified a report. Because if I changed the Specifiy a Report using only AccountDetailReport (without expression), it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Try creating two placeholders in your tables column, both in the same cell.  The value expression will be the same (whatever you currently have in the column) .

You can then set the 1st placeholder to be visible when the total won > 0 and this placeholder can have an action to go to the sub report. The 2nd placeholder can be set to hidden when the total won value > 0 and have no action assigned.